# jQuery ToggleClass optimisation and features

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have worked on the below code to control a series of 3 sidebars. As you can see, the code isn't particularly efficient as I've simply repeated the content for each class. I'd like to streamline this if possible to just one function?

I'd also like to add the functionality of only ever allowing one sidebar to be active. So if sidebar `.artists` is `.active` and I click sidebar `.about`, the `.artists` sidebar will collapse.

Thanks.

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".artists" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.artists" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( ".about" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.about" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( ".history" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.history" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="artists"><a>Artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=get_permalink(6)?>">News</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a>About</a></li>
        <li class="history"><a>History</a></li>         
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="sidebar artists">
    Sidebar Artists content
</nav>

<nav class="sidebar about">
    Sidebar About content
</nav>

<nav class="sidebar history">
    Sidebar History content
</nav>
```

Comment: First thing, you don't need `$(function() {` AKA `ready` that many times.

Comment: Are there multiple elements having the class `artists`, `about` and `history`?

Comment: Hi @Tushar. No the classes apply to one sidebar each. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to optimize it:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sidebar" ).click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
         $(".active").toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

As per markup code I would suggest you to add an ID to the main `ul` as `main-nav`:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#main-nav li" ).click(function() {

        var cls = this.className;

        $(this).addClass( "active" )
         .siblings("li").removeClass( "active" );

         $(".sidebar."+cls).slideToggle()
           .siblings(".sidebar").slideUp();

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai. Any idea how to implement the other feature in the question?

Comment: Just updated the answer a bit, I hope you would like it.

Comment: Hi @Jai this is great thank you. Is there a way to retain the ability to toggle a single sidebar by clicking the relevant <li>? At the moment once clicked one sidebar always has to remain active. It would be great to be able to toggle this and possibly introduce a button that could close all sidebars?

Comment: Any suggestions @Jai?

Answer (score 0):

**As you have given the markup, I have changed my code.**

*Try this:*

> I have checked this code and it works properly

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul li').on('click',function(){
     $('.sidebar').hide();
     $(this).parent().parent().siblings("." +$(this).attr('class')).show();
   });
 });
```

Alternatively using `active` class

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
     $('.sidebar').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent().parent().siblings("." +$(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
 });
```

***Here's the fiddle example:***
http://jsfiddle.net/5angwsnb/3/

> Hope it works well for you too!

**Update:**

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar{
   display:none;
 }
.active{
   //your transition here
 }
```

Comment: No luck with this @Sumit. It simply hides all of the sidebars. Unfortunately not what I was after.

Comment: I didn't get, I will update the code as per your requirement. It shows one at a time which is clicked. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Firstly, I don't want to use .hide(); as I want to transition the sidebars off to the side of the page. I also don't want any of them to be displayed initially, only on click. If possible I'd also like to add the .active class to the corresponding menu item?

Comment: two items you said i updated. Third item is simple using `$('ul li').removeClass('active');` and `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: You can also use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` for animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.artists, .about, .history').click(function() {

    var subClass = '';
    if($(this).hasClass('artists')) {
        subClass = 'artists';
    } else if($(this).hasClass('about')) {
        subClass = 'about';
    } else if($(this).hasClass('history')) {
        subClass = 'history';
    }

    $('.sidebar:not(.'+subClass+')').removeClass('active');
    $('.sidebar.'+subClass).toggleClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aua0wxm9/3/

Comment: Nothing functioning in that fiddle for me?

Comment: Works great in your fiddle now but when implemented on my site any click adds .active to .history and none of the others?